# Erro ao tentar salvar o script no R

Tags: r

Quando tento salvar meu script aparece a mensagem de erro conforme imagem.
Como resolver esse problema?

[image: Erro apresentado no R]

Comment: Já tentou fechar a sessão RStudio e recomeçar? Esse erro é um erro do sistema operativo, não do `R`.

Comment: Já tentei e mesmo assim continua a aparecer esse erro a cada vez que tento salvar o script.

Comment: Então o ficheiro está a ser usado por outro processo. Não estará a correr outro processo RStudio? (Isto supondo que só usou o RStudio para abrir o script.)

Comment: Reinstalei o Rstudio e deixou de apresentar o erro.

Comment: Reinstalei o Rstudio e deixou de dar erro.